# Calculate from tile URL path a TileCache URL path

Tags: tiles, tilecache, tile-map-service

I am searching for a way how to calculate in PHP (there for OpenLayers are not suitable for me) from tile path /zoom/x/y.png a Tilecache URL like 14/000/009/107/000/010/749.png

Comment: Can you not just parse the GetCapabilities response for the server?

Comment: I am totaly new, what is GetCapabilities doing?

Comment: It's the document that describes the operations of the service

Comment: But this doesnt help me, I am going to do that php will get tile from tilecache based on tile path

Comment: But the path might not be guessable. The document gives you the location

Comment: I see, ok so how can I do a request for example on this server which serves tiles? https://mapy.hiking.sk/layers/laviny/14/000/009/107/000/010/749.png